# Get current URL from IFRAME

Tags: javascript, url, iframe

Is there a simple way to get the current URL from an iframe?

The viewer would going through multiple sites. 
I'm guessing I would be using something in javascript.

Comment: If you came here looking for the URL of the "parent" page of the iframe, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/3420004/32453

Comment: As a browser user, how do I check the url of a webpage in an IFRAME. Once there was a `property` in the right click menu, but it was gotten rid of by the browser.

Answer (score 210, accepted):

For security reasons, you can only get the url for as long as the contents of the iframe, and the referencing javascript, are served from the same domain. As long as that is true, something like this will work:

```
document.getElementById("iframe_id").contentWindow.location.href
```

If the two domains are mismatched, you'll run into cross site reference scripting security restrictions.

See also [answers to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44359/how-do-i-get-the-current-location-of-an-iframe).

Comment: There is no winning answer in the question I linked... if you mean the topmost answer, it isn't really a working solution. With IE, you could try the HTA approach provided also in the answers to the aforementioned question.

Comment: What if we add the attribute `sandbox="allow-same-origin"` to the iFrame?

Comment: And if we allow the new source on the Iframe's target server, would we run into a problem?

Comment: Another way: `window.frames[0].location.href`

Comment: Simplest: `window.top.location.href`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/top

Answer (score 26):

If your iframe is from another domain, (cross domain), the other answers are not going to help you... you will simply need to use this:

```
var currentUrl = document.referrer;
```

and - here you've got the main url!

Comment: -1 the OP is looking for the current url of the iframe, not the referrer of the parent page.

Comment: @Christophe - I know, but it can help people looking for getting the main url and came to this question!

Comment: that will not give You the top most (try with 2 nested iframes), but even thinking just about one level, it is too easy to fake it thus You cannot absolutely rely on it!

Comment: Aslo: `document.getElementById("iframe").contentDocument.referrer`

Comment: You save my life, thats exacly what i need

Answer (score 5):

I had an issue with blob url hrefs.  So, with a reference to the iframe, I just produced an url from the iframe's src attribute:

```
    const iframeReference = document.getElementById("iframe_id");
    const iframeUrl = iframeReference ? new URL(iframeReference.src) : undefined;
    if (iframeUrl) {
        console.log("Voila: " + iframeUrl);
    } else {
        console.warn("iframe with id iframe_id not found");
    }
```

Comment: This works for me, and doesn't need to be on same host

Answer (score 4):

If you are in the iframe context,

you could do

```
const currentIframeHref = new URL(document.location.href);
const urlOrigin = currentIframeHref.origin;
const urlFilePath = decodeURIComponent(currentIframeHref.pathname);
```

If you are in the parent window/frame, then you can use https://stackoverflow.com/a/938195/2305243 's answer, which is

```
document.getElementById("iframe_id").contentWindow.location.href
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're inside an iframe that don't have cross domain src, or src is empty:

Then:

```
function getOriginUrl() {
    var href = document.location.href;
    var referrer = document.referrer;
    // Check if window.frameElement not null
    if(window.frameElement) {
        href = window.frameElement.ownerDocument.location.href;
        // This one will be origin
        if(window.frameElement.ownerDocument.referrer != "") {
            referrer = window.frameElement.ownerDocument.referrer;
        }
    }
    // Compare if href not equal to referrer
    if(href != referrer) {
        // Take referrer as origin
        return referrer;
    } else {
        // Take href
        return href
    }
}
```

If you're inside an iframe with cross domain src:

Then:

```
function getOriginUrl() {
    var href = document.location.href;
    var referrer = document.referrer;
    // Detect if you're inside an iframe
    if(window.parent != window) {
        // Take referrer as origin
        return referrer;
    } else {
        // Take href
        return href;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help some how in your case,
I suffered with the exact same problem, and just used localstorage to share the data between parent window and iframe.
So in parent window you can:

```
localStorage.setItem("url", myUrl);
```

And in code where iframe source is just get this data from localstorage:

```
localStorage.getItem('url');
```

Saved me a lot of time.
As far as i can see the only condition is access to the parent page code.
Hope this will help someone.

Comment: local storage works only on the same domain... so why going with all of this trouble? simply query the location.href

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to retrieve the full URL from the inside of the shopify google analytics additional script iframe. `document.refferer` shows only hostname without search params. But I found another property that worked for me `document.baseURI`

Answer (score -1):

Some additional information for anyone who might be struggling with this:

You'll be getting null values if you're trying to get URL from iframe before it's loaded.
I solved this problem by creating the whole iframe in javascript and getting the values I needed with the onLoad function:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.onload = function() {

    //some custom settings
    this.width=screen.width;this.height=screen.height; this.passing=0; this.frameBorder="0";

    var href = iframe.contentWindow.location.href;
    var origin = iframe.contentWindow.location.origin;
    var url = iframe.contentWindow.location.url;
    var path = iframe.contentWindow.location.pathname;

    console.log("href: ", href)
    console.log("origin: ", origin)
    console.log("path: ", path)
    console.log("url: ", url)
};

iframe.src = 'http://localhost/folder/index.html';

document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

Because of the same-origin policy, I had problems when accessing "cross origin" frames - I solved that by running a webserver locally instead of running all the files directly from my disk. In order for all of this to work, you need to be accessing the iframe with the same protocol, hostname and port as the origin. Not sure which of these was/were missing when running all files from my disk.

Also, more on location objects: https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/obj_location.asp

Answer (score -1):

Not a simple way, but not particularly difficult either. Execute `document.documentElement.outerHTML` and you'll get the complete source of the "surrounding" page. From there it is easy to use a regular expression to search for the URL of the iframe.

Comment: The would give the value of the `src` attribute, which is the *initial* URL, not the *current* URL.

Comment: @Quentin You are right, but why does it seem to be blocked to get the initial URL using more regular methods (class, ID) when it is easy to access it this way?

Comment: It isn't. https://jsbin.com/mopohugica/1/edit?html,js,output