# Access parent URL from iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain

Okay, I have a page on and on this page I have an iframe.  What I need to do is on the iframe page, find out what the URL of the main page is.

I have searched around and I know that this is not possible if my iframe page is on a different domain, as that is cross-site scripting. But everywhere I've read says that if the iframe page is on the same domain as the parent page, it should work if I do for instance:

```
parent.document.location
```

```
parent.window.document.location
```

```
parent.window.location
```

```
parent.document.location.href
```

... or other similar combos, as there seems to be multiple ways to get the same info.

Anyways, so here's the problem.  My iframe is on the same domain as the main page, but it is not on the same SUB domain.  So for instance I have

> http:// www.mysite.com/pageA.html

and then my iframe URL is

> http:// qa-www.mysite.com/pageB.html

When I try to grab the URL from `pageB.html` (the iframe page), I keep getting the same access denied error.  So it appears that even sub-domains count as cross-site scripting, is that correct, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you just pass it in the frame URL? Such as `<iframe src="url?parent=parent-url"></iframe>`

Comment: seems like for FF passing it as a param would be nice work around until they implement it https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1835377

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You're correct. Subdomains are still considered separate domains when using iframes. It's possible to pass messages using [`postMessage(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage), but other JS APIs are intentionally made inaccessible.

It's also still possible to get the URL depending on the context. See other answers for more details.

Comment: you CAN interact between the 2. But you must add the following script on both parent and iframe: <script>document.domain="mydomain.com";</script>

Answer (score 468):

Yes, accessing parent page's URL is not allowed if the iframe and the main page are not in the same (sub)domain. However, if you just need the URL of the main page (i.e. the browser URL), you can try this:

```
var url = (window.location != window.parent.location)
            ? document.referrer
            : document.location.href;
```

**Note:**

`window.parent.location` is allowed; it avoids the security error in the OP, which is caused by accessing the `href` property: `window.parent.location.href` causes "Blocked a frame with origin..."

[`document.referrer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer) refers to "the URI of the page that linked to this page." This may **not** return the *containing* document if some other source is what determined the `iframe` location, for example:

- Container iframe @ Domain 1
- Sends child iframe to Domain 2
- But in the child iframe... Domain 2 redirects to Domain 3 (i.e. for authentication, maybe SAML), and then Domain 3 directs *back* to Domain 2 (i.e. via form submission(), a standard SAML technique)
- For the child iframe the `document.referrer` will be Domain **3**, not the containing Domain **1**

[`document.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/location) refers to "a Location object, which contains information about the URL of the document"; presumably the **current** document, that is, the iframe currently open. When `window.location === window.parent.location`, then the iframe's `href` is the *same* as the containing parent's `href`.

Comment: @Ash it'll if the window and the parent window location's are different, you're inside of an iframe. In that case, it takes the referrer of the iframe. Otherwise, it's the main window, thus takes document.location (referrer is invalid here, since it'd be the previous page and not the parent).

Comment: @jepser that is because your iframe is inside that iframe. you will never have access to the top frame with that one in the middle. nested cross domain iframes is wrong on so many levels. but you may be able to get around that if you set `document.domain` on the top frame and the inner-most one. maybe.

Comment: This answer combined with http://stackoverflow.com/a/5697801/216084 gets the job done.

Comment: Or, slightly more compactly: `var url = (parent !== window) ? document.referrer : document.location;`

Comment: Please note that it doesn't work if the container is located on your localhost (or more generally, if this page is not open by a web server) or called by file://.

Comment: It should be noted that this can be defeated with the [`Referer-Policy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy) header.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with Edge browser - the referrer will be an empty string..

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24169219/on-ie-10-will-document-referrer-be-blank-when-read-inside-an-iframe

Comment: @thekingoftruth even more concise: `var url = (self===top) ? document.URL : document.referrer;` (two changes: (1) using positive instead of negative check; (2) `document.location` is an object, so you need to use `document.location.href` or `document.URL`).

Comment: Will this work if the container is running on ngrok?

Comment: Tried this after several other solutions and it worked! In my case, the script was executed inside a frame located at the main page, with different urls but same host.

Comment: This solution won't work if the parent page has ` <meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer" />`

Comment: This solution does not wok. Chrome is blocking redirect.

Comment: This does not include path, query strings, or fragment identifiers.

Answer (score 70):

I just discovered a workaround for this problem that is so simple, and yet I haven't found any discussions anywhere that mention it.  It does require control of the parent frame.

In your iFrame, say you want this iframe: src="http://www.example.com/mypage.php"

Well, instead of HTML to specify the iframe, use a javascript to build the HTML for your iframe, get the parent url through javascript "at build time", and send it as a url GET parameter in the querystring of your src target, like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  url = parent.document.URL;
  document.write('<iframe src="http://example.com/mydata/page.php?url=' + url + '"></iframe>');
</script>
```

Then, find yourself a javascript url parsing function that parses the url string to get the url variable you are after, in this case it's "url".

I found a great url string parser here:
http://www.netlobo.com/url_query_string_javascript.html

Comment: This answer combined with http://stackoverflow.com/a/7739035/216084 gets the job done.

Comment: This was a wonderful suggestion. For those who are writing the parent html iframe code this would foot the bill. We used something very similar in our pixel software.

Comment: Thank you!!  This is an effective work-around that still respects cross-site rules.

Comment: But do you rewrite all the urls in the html at the server? Because otherwise when an user clicks a link in the iFrame it will still not be accessable.

Comment: @Roel you could write them all at server time (in essence, "hard code" this answer), or this answer you could do in javascript, for instance after the page loads it injects the desired iframes.

Comment: document.write is considered sort of bad practice for a variety of reasons. It might work, but you should use it with caution.  Here's an interesting blog about it: https://blog.dareboost.com/en/2016/09/avoid-using-document-write-scripts-injection/.  Along with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18789190/why-not-document-write

Comment: `Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://blah.net" from accessing a cross-origin frame.`

Comment: You may want to do `encodeURIComponent(url)` and no need for `parent.` in `parent.document.URL;` unless you are nesting iFrames (not a great idea) Also a PHP script should know its own url `"https://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"` so your answer is better suited for html pages

Answer (score 50):

The following line will work: `document.location.ancestorOrigins[0]` this one returns the ancestor domain name.

Comment: Following changes made to Chrome, this is now the correct answer for a lot of browsers.

Comment: Not the full url though. Only the domain

Comment: `document.location.ancestorOrigins` returns `undefined` for me

Comment: Regarding browser support, specifically, as of July 2020, ancestorOrigins is not yet supported in Firefox due to privacy concerns. Bugzilla feature request and discussion: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1085214. Browser support: https://caniuse.com/#search=ancestorOrigins

Comment: You might want the last item: `document.location.ancestorOrigins[document.location.ancestorOrigins.length - 1]` since ancestorOrigins is "in reverse order, the origins of all ancestor browsing contexts of the document associated with the given Location object." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/ancestorOrigins
For example, my site shows a https://*.github.io site, so the first item was that https://*.github.io site, but I want the original page and what the browser shows.

Answer (score 44):

If your iframe is from another domain, (cross domain), you will simply need to use this:

```
var currentUrl = document.referrer;
```

and - here you've got the main url!

Comment: That didn't work in my case as I think the iFrame itself has been dynamically generated or did some other trickery. I did not get the answer I expected at any rate.

Comment: this should work in all browsers. Unless in newer browsers if you send Sandboxing parameters, but i doubt this is the case. This works regardless of cross domain.

Comment: If the page inside the iframe reloaded itself via javascript (e.g. `window.location.reload(true)`) this doesn't work anymore. Then referrer is the URL of the iframe itself.

Answer (score 20):

For pages on the same domain and different subdomain, you can set the `document.domain` property via javascript.

Both the parent frame and the iframe need to set their document.domain to something that is common betweeen them.

i.e.
`www.foo.mydomain.com` and `api.foo.mydomain.com` could each use either `foo.mydomain.com` or just `mydomain.com` and be compatible (no, you can't set them both to `com`, for security reasons...)

also, note that document.domain is a one way street.  Consider running the following three statements in order:

```
// assume we're starting at www.foo.mydomain.com
document.domain = "foo.mydomain.com" // works
document.domain = "mydomain.com" // works
document.domain = "foo.mydomain.com" // throws a security exception
```

Modern browsers can also use window.postMessage to talk across origins, but it won't work in IE6.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage

Answer (score 16):

There's a lot a answers to this question, and none of them are definitely the best in terms of support or reliability.

### Options

- `window.location.ancestorOrigins[0]` will get the parent url, but this api only works in chromium browsers (see [support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/ancestorOrigins#browser_compatibility)). this also supports nested iframes, where the bottom most child has access to the urls of each parent iframe.
- `document.referrer` is the most common answer but is not always reliable

  - navigation inside of the iframe would show the last page instead of the parent frame url
  - redirects only show the most recent referrer to the current page
  - if the page reloads itself the referer becomes the page itself
  - [http child with an https parent has an empty string for referrer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16551646/2932782)

#### Things that don't work

- `window.parent.location.href`. If the parent and the child are in different domains, this api is blocked by modern browsers (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25098153/2932782)), and will throw an error.

### Recommendation

If supported, I prefer `window.location.ancestorOrigins[0]`. `document.referrer` can work, but is less reliable, making it my fallback option. If you do use document referrer, try to call it on the first framed page load, before navigation or redirects, to get the parent address.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out where document.referrer is inconsistent.

Answer (score 15):

Try it:

```
document.referrer
```

When you change you are in a iframe your host is "referrer".

Comment: Today, in Chrome, this is not returning the full URL. When `example.com?abc=123` loads an iframe, and you run `document.referrer` on the iframe, it only gives `example.com` and strips the `?abc=123` part.

Comment: Any update on this? I need the path/search portion of the URL as well

Comment: @iuliu.net Have you found anything other than postMessage, as I also want to access `domain/section` of the URL?

Answer (score 4):

there is a cross browser script for get parent origin:

```
private getParentOrigin() {
  const locationAreDisctint = (window.location !== window.parent.location);
  const parentOrigin = ((locationAreDisctint ? document.referrer : document.location) || "").toString();

  if (parentOrigin) {
    return new URL(parentOrigin).origin;
  }

  const currentLocation = document.location;

  if (currentLocation.ancestorOrigins && currentLocation.ancestorOrigins.length) {
    return currentLocation.ancestorOrigins[0];
  }

  return "";
}
```

This code, should work on Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 3):

```
var url = (window.location != window.parent.location) ? document.referrer: document.location;
```

I found that the above example suggested previously worked when the script was being executed in an iframe however it did not 
retrieve the url when the script was executed outside of an iframe, 
a slight adjustment was required:

```
var url = (window.location != window.parent.location) ? document.referrer: document.location.href;
```

Comment: If you outside the iframe then you are running the script ON the parent frame, you don't need to check anything.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you get to tell the parent page how to set up the iframe, to easily but **insecurily** get the full URL with a path and URL parameters, include `referrerpolicy="unsafe-url"` when specifying the iframe:

```
<iframe src="https://example.com/innersite" referrerpolicy="unsafe-url" title="My Title"></iframe>
```

Then you can get the full original URL with:

```
document.referrer
```

Many of the other answers only work when the iframe src is the same as the parent's domain.

### Fallbacks:

In case there are security issues, you could do a fallback like https://stackoverflow.com/a/5697801/1226799 says where the parent explicitly sends its URL in a URL parameter for the iframe URL, **but an attacker could easily fake that.**

I believe you could also use message passing and check the origin of the event: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61548595/1226799

Answer (score 2):

I've had issues with this.  If using a language like php when your page first loads in the iframe grab `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFFERER']` and set it to a session variable.

This way when the page loads in the iframe you know the full parent url and query string of the page that loaded it.  With cross browser security it's a bit of a headache counting on window.parent anything if you you different domains.

Answer (score 2):

I've found in the cases where `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` doesn't work (I'm looking at you, Safari), `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_SCRIPT_URI']` has been a useful backup.

Answer (score 1):

I couldnt get previous solution to work but I found out that if I set the iframe scr with for example `http:otherdomain.com/page.htm?from=thisdomain.com/thisfolder` then I could, in the iframe extract `thisdomain.com/thisfolder` by using following javascript:

```
var myString = document.location.toString();
var mySplitResult = myString.split("=");
fromString = mySplitResult[1];
```

Comment: Technically this solution works, but this is not the secure way of doing it. This way a hacker can embed your page on his website and pass a URL you expect as string. Your iframe code can't detect this and will accept the URL and process the data.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the PHP $_SERVER['HTTP_REFFERER'] is that it gives the fully qualified page url of the page that brought you to the parent page. That's not the same as the parent page, itself. Worse, sometimes there is no http_referer, because the person typed in the url of the parent page. So, if I get to your parent page from yahoo.com, then yahoo.com becomes the http_referer, not your page.

Answer (score 1):

In chrome it is possible to use location.ancestorOrigins
It will return all parent urls

Comment: That just has domains, not full URLs with paths and URL parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access the `window.parent.location` if the iframe is not in the same subdomain. The solution to this problem is to use `document.referrer`

You can simply access the parent's page complete URL by doing

```
const isIframe = window.self !== window.top;
const url = isIframe ? document.referrer : document.location.href;
```

Later in order to get the URL search query you can

```
const searchQuery = url?.split('?')?.[1] || ''
```

Note:
Because of security concerns, the referrer policy is set to `strict-origin-when-cross-origin` which means that only if the iframe is not in the same subdomain then the `document.referrer` will only return the origin and not the query params.

In order to overcome it, you can set the following attribute to the iframe element

```
referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"
```

This is the most secure and reliable way to get the search query from the URL.

Answer (score -3):

This worked for me to access the iframe src url.

```
window.document.URL
```

Answer (score -3):

I know his is super old but it blows my mind no one recommended just passing cookies from one domain to the other. As you are using subdomains you can share cookies from a base domain to all subdomains just by setting cookies to the url `.basedomain.com`

Then you can share whatever data you need through the cookies.

Answer (score -4):

Get All Parent Iframe functions and HTML

```
var parent = $(window.frameElement).parent();
        //alert(parent+"TESTING");
        var parentElement=window.frameElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement;
        var Ifram=parentElement.children;      
        var GetUframClass=Ifram[9].ownerDocument.activeElement.className;
        var Decision_URLLl=parentElement.ownerDocument.activeElement.contentDocument.URL;
```

Comment: I don't suppose you can expand this answer for those of us who don't use jQuery (a growing number, I should point out, since jQuery has become increasing unnecessary over the last few years).  At the very least, I suggest making it clear this answer is dependent on jQuery and the OP didn't mention jQuery at all.