# javascript not showing alert

Tags: javascript

This code is not showing me alert:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var wloc = window.parent.location;
var abcd = wloc.substring(0,24);
alert(wloc);
alert(abcd);
</script>
```

Comment: That's because `location` is not a string, it's a `location` object.

Comment: @FelixKling ok so how i can get the value of `window.parent.location` in a string?

Comment: Location has a href property, as in `location.href`

Comment: @TheZ It still does not work.

Comment: You cannot access `window.parent` if the parent page is from a different domain.

Comment: @FelixKling Yes it is from a different domain. So how i can resolve it?

Comment: check for the exception as i did in my answer if its still not working for you

Comment: I don't think you can. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420004/access-parent-url-from-iframe. What is your final goal?

Comment: @Felix Kling Actually I am making a facebook app and want to redirect the user to some other website. In facebook app I have my code in a frame, as facebook provides frames for applications

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that your script has access to `parent`. Then modify script as given below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
    var wloc = window.parent.location.href;
    var abcd = wloc.substring(0,24);
    alert(wloc);
    alert(abcd);
}
</script>
```

For location of current window try the script below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
    var wloc = window.location.href;
    var abcd = wloc.substring(0,24);
    alert(wloc);
    alert(abcd);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

add `.href` after `window.parent.location`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
    var wloc = window.parent.location.href;
    var abcd = wloc.substring(0,24);
    alert(wloc);
    alert(abcd);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below line is giving error. That's why it doesn't showing alert.

```
var abcd = wloc.substring(0,24);
```

Use this instead

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function(){
    var wloc = window.parent.location.href;
    var abcd = wloc.substring(0,24);
    alert(wloc);
    alert(abcd);
 }
</script>
```