# Change background image of an iframe body with Jquery if certain URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I use the following jQuery script to read the page URL and according to this I change the background image:

**Sort version of my script:**

```
var url = window.location.href;
if (url.search("food") > 0){
    alert('Example: use image 1');
} else {
    alert('Example: use image 2');
}
```

This script works well when the page loads *independent*. However, it's not working when the page is called from an `iframe`, meaning that the script cannot read parent's window URL. Is there any way to get the URL of the parent window from the page that's called in the `iframe`? I hope it makes sense.

**--EDIT--**

I have full control of both pages: The page with the `iframe` and the page that's been called in the `iframe`. Maybe an alternative would be to have a script in the *parent* page that changes the background image of the `iframe` page.

**--SOLUTION--**

`parent.document.location.href` did the trick and since my `iframe` is in the same domain but in different subdomain I had to declare also: `document.domain = "myurl.com"`. So my final script now is:

```
document.domain = "mydomain.com";
var url = parent.document.location.href;
if (url.search("food") > 0){
    alert('Example: use image 1');
} else {
    alert('Example: use image 2');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `window.parent.location.href` from the iframe. This can work as long as both the iframe and parent are on the same domain.

Also, see this related post: [Access parent URL from iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420004/access-parent-url-from-iframe)

Comment: I should have researched a bit more... Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

OP,

[This solution](http://plnkr.co/edit/evGubLPq4GrsFAK4EeYv?p=preview) uses jQuery to access the (same domain) iframe's content/apply css styling.