# How to get Http_Referrer of host site when calls come from iFrame?

Tags: javascript, .net, http, web

I have a module which reads Http Calls to get Http_Referrer and operate on it. Now, recently I have had to put my client page inside an iFrame for a different host site. When this happens, I would like to be able know what is the url of the Host site. How can I achieve this using HttpRequest object?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing parent page's URL is not allowed if the iframe and the main page are not in the same (sub)domain, there are some gimmicky workarounds using http referrer, but they are not reliable

See More detailed SO here [Access parent URL from iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420004/access-parent-url-from-iframe)

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments. I used the var url = (window.location != window.parent.location) ? document.referrer: document.location; and it worked for me. I was debugging my code and realized that from my iFrame, just window.location gives me pparent url. The code does not have to go as far as document.referrer and there I am. Now, having read all the articles about how cross-site scripting is not allowed, I really find this too good to be true. It works for me but I am just wondering if I did something stupid!!!

Comment: One issue is when users directly type the URL , there is no referrer, so the value could be the last page they visited, like yahoo.com, least that's my understanding