# How can I disable someone from loading a page in an iframe and using javascript to submit?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, exploit

Title says it all.

Imagine this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<iframe style="display:none" name="xxx"></iframe>
<form method='POST' action='http://MYPAGE.com/account/' target="xxx" id="xxx">
  <input type='hidden' name='xxxxxxx' value='yyyyyyyy'>
  <input type='submit' value='submit'>
</form>
<script>document.getElementById("xxx").submit()</script>
</body>
```

How can I disable an attack like that?

Comment: If the page in the iFrame is a different domain (even sub domain) it will NOT have access to the parent. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3420026/1861459

Comment: The iframe is pretty irrelevant here.

Comment: @pherris — The question isn't about the iframe having access to the parent, it is about the page submitting a form to `http://MYPAGE.com/account/`

Comment: This is answered by the CSRF tag wiki: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/csrf/info

Comment: Vice versa - the parent is accessing the iframed page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `X-Frame-Options` and set it to `DENY` or `SAMEORIGIN`. `DENY` will completely deny anybody from framing the page in an iframe and `SAMEORIGIN` will only allow the same origin to display the page in an iframe. See https://coderwall.com/p/kdv1hw for more information.