# Tabs open url links in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code written using Angular JS. I am trying to get the tabs to open urls when I click on the tab header. Please help.

```
<html ng-app="blp_tabs">
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js"></script>
<script>angular.module('blp_tabs', ['ui.bootstrap']);
  var TabsDemoCtrl = function ($scope) {
  $scope.tabs = [
    { title:"Google", url:"http://www.google.com" },
    { title:"CNN", url:"http://www.cnn.com", disabled: false }
  ];

  $scope.navType = 'tabs';
  };
</script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

 <div ng-controller="TabsDemoCtrl">
   <tabset>
     <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" active="tab.active" select="tab.url" disabled="tab.disabled">
     </tab>
   </tabset>
 </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

Changes are:

1. Use `iframe` html tag to load webpage (that is in your tab)
2. Use `$sce` [service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24sce) for using source URL of webpage in iframe

>

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="blp_tabs">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js"></script>
<script>
  angular.module('blp_tabs', ['ui.bootstrap']);
  var TabsDemoCtrl = function ($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.tabs = [
    { title:"Google", url:$sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://www.google.com") },
    { title:"CNN", url:$sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://www.cnn.com"), disabled: false }
  ];

  $scope.navType = 'tabs';
  };
</script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body >
 <div ng-controller="TabsDemoCtrl">
   <tabset >
     <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" >
       <iframe ng-src='{{tab.url}}' style="height:100%; width:100%;"></iframe>
     </tab>
   </tabset>
 </div>
</body>
```

**Edit 1** (To change the url of main page on tab click. I'm still not sure why someone will change url of main page after click operation on tab title. Hope you've some good reason for that):

> ```
> <html ng-app="blp_tabs">
> <head>
> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.min.js"></script>
>   <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js"></script>
> <script>
>   angular.module('blp_tabs', ['ui.bootstrap']);
>   var TabsDemoCtrl = function ($scope, $sce, $window, $log) {
>     $scope.tabs = [
>       { title:"Google", url:$sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://www.google.com") },
>       { title:"CNN", url:$sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://www.cnn.com"), disabled: false }
>     ];
>     $scope.navType = 'tabs';
>     $scope.open = function(myUrl){
>         $window.location.href = myUrl;
>     }
>   };
> </script>
> <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
> </head>
> <body >
>  <div ng-controller="TabsDemoCtrl">
>    <tabset >
>      <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" select='open(tab.url)'>
>      </tab>
>    </tabset>
>  </div>
> </body>
> ```

Comment: Sorry I need to load the page in the parent, when the user clicks on a given tab.

Comment: parent? can you please describe it more?

Comment: I want the page to open in the parent page not the iframe.

Comment: Let me confirm if i understood you correctly. You want to open google or cnn whenever user clicks on tab. The new page should open in same browser that means your HTML webpage containing your-tab will be replaced by google/cnn webpage. Is that correct?

Comment: correct. Also please note that the entire code snippet is sitting in an iframe itself. I should have mentioned this before. Apologies.

Comment: In that case, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420004/access-parent-url-from-iframe could be helpful.

Comment: For some reason the text on the tabs show {{tab.title}} rather than the actual title. Any idea ?