# On IE 10+, will document.referrer be blank when read inside an iFrame?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe, internet-explorer-11

On all other recent browsers, reading `document.referrer` from an app which runs inside an iframe would return the URL of the parent site. On IE 11, however, it seems to be returning an empty string. I want to confirm whether this is the expected behaviour on IE 10+, but googling hasn't turned up much about this particular scenario.

MS's [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534365%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a bit vague:

> This property returns a value only when the user reaches the current document through a link from the previous document. Otherwise, document.referrer returns an empty string;

I don't know if the above covers iFrame's or not, and then there is this bit:

> it also returns an empty string when the link is from a secure site.

The parent app is indeed a secure https site, but so is our iframe app. Does this mean that we won't be able to read this property from within our iframe on IE 10+? Thanks

Comment: I would think it will return an empty string as long as the link is from a secure site no matter if the current page is secure or not because the doc never mentions it

Comment: Reading MS's documentations leaves the impression that it's intended behavior. You don't load an iframe through a link from the previous document.

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered that the `document.referrer` property is also an empty string when an iframe has no `src` or a has a `javascript:` protocol for its `src`.

You can verify this quite easily in the developer tools:

```
var ifr = document.createElement('iframe');
document.body.appendChild(ifr);
ifr.contentDocument.referrer;
//-> '' in IE, '<parent location>' in Chrome
```