# How can I get the URL of the parent site of an iframe in IE11?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe, internet-explorer-11

According to the investigation in [On IE 10+, will document.referrer be blank when read inside an iFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24169219/on-ie-10-will-document-referrer-be-blank-when-read-inside-an-iframe)

in IE11, unlike other browsers, reading `document.referrer` cannot be used to get the URL of the parent site of an iframe. Then, how can I achieve this in IE11 using Javascript?

Comment: `parent.location` is what you're looking for. Of course, you have to have CORS access.

Answer (score 1):

if the iframe is in the same domain as the parent, you can use `window.parent` to access the containing document, so `window.parent.location` will be its URL.

Comment: Note that you don't have to type `window`, as it is implicit. `parent.location` is enough.

Comment: True, but it's sometimes helpful to be explicit, especially if there might be a local variable with the same name.

Comment: That's one way to look at it. Just trying to save OP some typing. We don't type `window.document.getElementById('idHere')`, do we? `window.parent.location.href` would also work.

Answer (score 0):

it's considered cross-site scripting and variously frowned upon, blocked etc. by system engineers and browsers. it's a security issue if a child iframe could get at (and hence manipulate) parent page. there are various hacks to get around it in various versions of browsers but it's been getting locked down better and better. You're supposed to be controlling both the hosting page and the iframe (same domain) and then write proper routines for those to interact via serverside ajax, instead of directly manipulating from within a frame. computer says NO.