# http request inside iframe - referrer missing

Tags: javascript, http, iframe, https

I have an app that people can use by adding to their website:

```
<script src="https://example.org/my-app"></script>
```

I am validating on my server which domain made the request so i can allow it or reject it. For this i am using `referrer`. So far i didnt have much of a problems. The problem however happened when someone included this script from inside of `iframe`. I made couple of tests myself and i was not able to force `iframe` to include `referrer` when its executing this script with url.

```
<iframe src="about:blank" referrerpolicy="origin" sandbox="allow-scripts">
    <meta name="referrer" content="origin" />
    <script src="https://example.org/my-app"></script>
</iframe>
```

above `iframe` is accessing my server but `referrer` is missing, is there a way to force it to be sent?

Comment: Just to check - you are checking the `referer` rather than (or as well as?) `referrer`?  The header was misspelt in the original RFQ and it stuck.  See [the MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer) which also links to the wikipedia page with more info.

Comment: yes, no `referer`, no `referrer`, no `origin`, no anything that would allow me to read where request originated

Comment: See [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39411526/4098951) It seems that inserting the iframe contents in this way results in no referrer property (or I should say an empty string, which I can verify after a quick test on Firefox).

Comment: If you have access to your server you can get the `referer` header at the server side and respond accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the `document.referrer` is also empty in case of mixed content (regardless of the browser). e.g. parent page served via HTTPS and src within iframe served as regular HTTP.

```
<!-- Some page loaded over HTTPS -->
<iframe src="http://..." ></iframe>
```

Note, that loading mixed content can be enabled (which isn't allowed by default) on Chrome via the experimental flags. More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18321032/how-to-get-chrome-to-allow-mixed-content)