# Domain Restriction for embedded video iframe (JSP / Servlet)

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, iframe

I have developed a video sharing portal solution with a function similar to video sharing website out there (youtube, dailymotion), whereby it allows generation of iframe HTML code that can be embedded on your website.

For example:

```
<iframe width="521" height="391" src="http://192.168.1.3/vidsolution/public/portal/embed/UlNBX0VuY3J5cHRpb25fMi5tcDQ=" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

So i would like to find out how can I achieve Domain restriction whereby the iframe will only show the player if the iframe is embedded on permited domain ?

I've found out that you can use javascript to check parent url:

[Link: access parent url from iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420004/access-parent-url-from-iframe)

Is that the most reliable way to do domain checking ? any alternative that doesn't involve Javascript, i.e. using JSP / Java Servlet checking ?

Thanks.

Comment: How should your servlet obtain the embedding pages URL if the request to your video originates from the web page users IP?

Comment: @Smutje Perhaps you can enlighten me on this ? What i need to find out what is the best method to perform domain restriction checking with the current implementation ?

Answer (score 0):

Use **temporary video URLs** (***secure link***) to restrict the access to the video by client IP for a certain period of time:

- The **Web site**, displaying the videos and the **video server** exchange a shared `secretKey` (only once, during the setup).
- The Web site, which renders the video player, at the server side, generates a **temporary URL**, for the video it wants to display, restricted by **client IP** and **expiration date**. A different temporary URL is generated at the server side for each client HTTP request. The temporary restricted video URL looks like at this example: `https://videos.mysite.com/play/videoID/expirationDate/{hash}/`
- The `{hash}` is calculated as SHA256(secretKey + videoID + expirationDate + clientIP)
- The video server calculates the same `{hash}` for the requested video and provides the video stream only if the `{hash}` is correct.

Both **Web site** and **video server** know all the details, needed to calculate the **hash**:

- **client IP address** (taken from the HTTP request, then passed to the video server as parameter)
- **videoID** (passed as parameter)
- **secretKey** (it is exchanged during the setup)
- **expiration date** (generated by the Web site as current date and time + 4 hours, then passed to the video server as parameter)

### Secure Links in nginx

The above described video link protection mechanism is known as "***secure links***" and is implemented out-of-the-box in the **nginx secure link module**:

- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_secure_link_module.html

Such an implementation is **highly secure** and is almost impossible to bypass (unless the client downloads the video and uploads it elsewhere), but it involves **server-side logic at the Web site**, which displays the video.

Similar "***secure link***"-based access restriction is used by Amazon S3, Facebook videos and many CDN networks.

### Pure Client-Side Implementation?

If you want to skip the server-side logic, and encapsulate the "**secure link**" unlock logic in an **easy-to-embed JavaScript video player**, you could generate the temporary secure link for the video in your client-side JavaScript code, but attackers can reverse engineer the code and reveal the secret key.

I don't how to implement secure link generation securely purely at the client-side.

Answer (score 0):

### Addition: Domain-Level Restriction

Most video servers use the **`Referer` HTTP header** to implement **domain-level restriction** for accessing the domain-protected embedded videos.

This **cannot be easily tricked at the client-side**, because modern Web browsers disallow changing the **`Referer` HTTP header** from a client-side JavaScript `fetch` (AJAX) calls.

#### Bypassing by Server-Side Proxy

Beware: the **`Referer` HTTP header**-based domain restriction can be **bypassed by a server-side script**, which requests the video with **spoofed HTTP referer** and re-streams it to the client (as proxy).

For example, the **"*domain-level privacy*" for Vimeo videos can be bypassed by a server-side code**, which fakes the **`Referer` HTTP header** and the related cookies in a server-side HTTP request.

#### Bypassing by Client-Side Code Injection in Allowed Domain

An easy way to **watch a domain-level restricted video** (when you have its URL) is by client-side injection of the video player code in some allowed HTML page (using the Chrome DevTools).

Let's see an **example**. We have a **domain-restricted video in Vimeo**, which cannot be embedded in the `w3schools.com` domain (this domain is not allowed by Vimeo):

[image: Domain-restricted video from Vimeo -> access denied]

In the same time, the video owner allows this video to be embedded in the domain `softuni.org`. We can open https://softuni.org, click **[F12]** to show Chrome DevTools and **inject the video `<iframe>` code** somewhere in the HTML page from this allowed domain:

[image: Injecting the Vimeo code in allowed domain using Chrome DevTools]

Now the video plays correctly, overcoming the domain-level access restriction:

[image: Vimeo domain-level privacy bypassed using Chrome DevTools]

Note that this cannot be easily automated by a Web site developer, but can be done by end-users with tech expertise. User's can also use a browser add-on, which fakes the **`Referer` HTTP header**, e.g. see the ["Referer Control" add-on](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/referer-control/hnkcfpcejkafcihlgbojoidoihckciin) fro Chrome.