# Before IFRAME form is submitted, save the parent url to hidden field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, iframe

I show in iFrame my contact form (for leads). What I need to do is to save the parent url, then to insert this url to my hidden field before the form is submitted (or on the page load). I need to know from what url the form was submitted.

I have code that works only is chrome console. but when I put this code in the parent html the code is there but not working

```
jQuery(".gfiframe").contents().find("#gform_submit_button_1").click(function(){
    jQuery(".gfiframe").contents().find("#input_1_2").val('test');
});
```

To get the parent url I use

```
var $location = location.host;
```

Comment: I don't think you can get the URL of the parent from the iframe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420004/access-parent-url-from-iframe

Comment: @jwatts1980: the linked question/answer only applies if the iframe is on a different domain, if both are on the same domain, you _can_ get them to interact through `window.parent` or `window.top`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`location.host` is relative to the iframe. Instead, use `document.referrer` [jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/BrianDillingham/djeeoecq/)

When the iframe's HTTP headers are sent, the parent to the iframe is sent as the referrer, therefore using `document.referrer` will result in the iframe's parent URL

**Update:** Within your iframe, not externally, use jQuery to add the parent url to the form being submitted

```
$('input.parent_url').val(document.referrer);
```

Comment: Hi sorry for delay. this did not help me because the ifame and the parent on different locations.<br> now i'm trying to make this work true Cross-Domain Messaging With postMessage

Comment: using `document.referrer` does exactly that as the example demonstrates. http://jsfiddle.net/djeeoecq/3/ the first alert is jsfiddle's iframe, and the second is the url of the page the iframe is within

Comment: You have to save the url from within the iframe, not access it from the parent