# Determining Iframe URL for foreign source frames

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, browser, same-origin-policy

Is there any way to identify the url being viewed in an iframe?  And is there any way to force the links in an iframe to be opened in a new tab/window?

Most importantly, can this be done notwithstanding the same original policy for foreign source frames?  And if not, why does this violate that policy?

By foreign I mean, not hosted by the same domain.  So for example, www.google.com is foreign to the website www.stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can get the url loaded inside an iframe is when the iframe's url points to the same domain that the parent. [Here is a good explanation of why you can't do that otherwise.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26055152/how-to-get-current-page-loaded-url-from-iframe)

Comment: But I don't understand HOW it is possible for the browser to render the page in the iframe, if it is IMPOSSIBLE to access the iframe.  Is there a solution if I can install software on the computer?  etc.