# How I can access to the parameters of an URL within of an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, url, iframe, openlayers

I have the following HTML with jQuery code:

```
<div id="info" style="width: 100%; height: 280px; overflow-y: scroll;"></div>

var url1 = cbcWMS1.getGetFeatureInfoUrl
(evt.coordinate, viewResolution, 'EPSG:3857', {'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html'});

$('#info').append('<iframe width="99%" seamless src="' + url1 + '"</iframe>');
```

The string `url1` returns an `iframe` element of a table with elements.

How can I access the elements in the `iframe`?

I would like to add a condition where if the `iframe` lacks contents, the whole `<div id='info'>` can be hidden using jQuery.

The string: `url1` contains the following code:

```
<body>
<table class="table table-hover table-condensed">
<h3>${type.name}</h3>
<head>
  <tr>
    <#list type.attributes as attribute>
      <#if !attribute.isGeometry> 
        <th>${attribute.name}</th> 
      </#if>
    </#list> 
  </tr>
</head>

<body>
  <#assign odd = false>
    <#if odd>
      <tr class="odd">
    <#else>
      <tr>
    </#if>
  <#assign odd = !odd>

  <#list features as feature>
    <#list feature.attributes as attribute>
      <#if !attribute.isGeometry>
        <td>${attribute.value}</td>
      </#if>
    </#list>
    </tr>
  </#list>
</body>
```

Comment: It really depends. If you generate the iframe, you could get it. If the iframe points to other domain or other subdomain of your current site, there is a problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420004/access-parent-url-from-iframe

Comment: If you generate the iframe you could write there a script get current url from document href and do your job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem changing the following part of my code:

`{'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html'}` to `{'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/json'}` .

Now, URL represent an `JSON` and not `HTML`.

So, It's definitely more easier to check and use the data.

Answer (score 0):

Use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) with [.contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/)

> Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched
>   elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

```
element = $("#info").find("#iframe_id").contents()
```

Comment: That will find the frame itself, which isn't what the question is asking about.