# How can i get the current src of an iframe which is redirected

Tags: javascript, facebook, iframe, redirect

I am making a manual login flow with facebook without js sdk i have an iframe to get user approval it works fine and returns short-lived access token withn url but  the problem when i want to get the url like `iframe.src` it returns the src i provided not redirected and which contains facebooks response.The question is how i can get  redirected current url of an iframe .
i tried 
`iframe.location.href` 
but it seems iframe doesnt have dom inside, and location is undefined.

Comment: Why not using the facebook javascript SDK ? Also, share code on how are you doing it through an iframe.

Comment: that's a weird way of doing it..

Comment: Try `document.referrer` see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420004/access-parent-url-from-iframe

Comment: nope it returns wrong value i tried already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out i can use `frame.contentWindow.location` after it returns to my site