# Test window.parent.location with Karma

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, karma-runner

```
  getIFrameParentUrl() {
    return (window.location !== window.parent.location)
      ? document.referrer
      : document.location.href;
  };
```

The code above is run from an i-frame checks if an i-frame is embedded and gets the url of the site embedding the iframe. I have no idea where to even begin with this one. Is this function testable in Karma? If so, how? I need a pointer in the right direction, not necessarily the code.

Running in PhantomJs, if that's relevant.

Source of function if anyone wants more background: [Access parent URL from iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420004/access-parent-url-from-iframe)

Comment: I am not familiar with Karma, but you can just write to window.parent. 
If it is possible to add some code just for tests consider using `window.postMessage()` and you will be able to listen for messages from parent window.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not always control the parent and cannot test as if I do.

Comment: PhantomJS can render just HTML you can embed your code in custom parent this way, can you do this with Karma?

Comment: Not sure, will look into it, thanks.