# Pass parent URL to form field within iframe

Tags: javascript

I have the same contact form iframe from one domain on multiple pages at another domain.  I'd like to be able to capture the parent page URL in a field in my iframe form.  Is this possible?  I'd prefer to use javascript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access parent URL from iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420004/access-parent-url-from-iframe)

Comment: Not duplicate because I need to 'pull' the URL into the iframe - not 'push' it from the parent page.

Answer (score 0):

document.referrer will hold the parent url

Comment: Thanks.  Where would I put that?  I am not very proficient in JS yet.  A sample page would be http://transcourt.com/bulk-tanker/ - with the iframe at the bottom being located at http://transcourt-iframe-form.sharing-online.net/.  The second page of the form is 2nd-form-english.  That's where the form field is that needs populating with the Parent URL.

Comment: I have had the website owner add <form name="Contact"> 
<input type=hidden name="name" value="bulk_tanker"> 
</form> to this page - along with the script <script>function transferField() {
   dat=document.Contact.name.value;
   window.maven-form.form_140303.forms[7cde51dc78906708f687e190b67a094b][64d96766e2183b7bd5d9ccf07e1bd430].value=dat;
}
window.onload=transferField;</script>.  The idea was to pass the subject of the site into a field in the iframe - so I could tell what page the contact was on when they visited the site.