# How to access parent URL from within an iframe originating from different domain?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have done an extensive research and read several threads on Stack Overflow. I realize that it is not quite simple when the domain origins for iframe and parent frame are different.

One of the recommended ways was to pass the URL from the parent frame using postMessage property. But the problem is that I am developing a website which will be used by other developers inside an iframe. So I cannot do anything from outside the iframe.

Unlike the following post where the iframe is on the same sub-domain, I want to know what to do when iframe is on an altogether different domain.
[Access parent URL from iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420004/access-parent-url-from-iframe)

How can I access parent URL using javascript or any other way?

Comment: Please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420004/access-parent-url-from-iframe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access parent URL from iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420004/access-parent-url-from-iframe)