# Iframe Cross-Origin Issue

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain

I want to know about iframe cross-origin.
Let’s say I have site : **load-me-from-iframe.com**
And I have another site named **iframe-loader.com** that will load site above.

How to know that **load-me-from-iframe.com** was loaded inside iframe from **iframe-loader.com** ?

In this case,  I will show the notification that will appear in **load-me-from-iframe.com** when it loaded from **iframe-loader.com**

Let me know and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this answer of any help:

[Access parent URL from iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420004/access-parent-url-from-iframe)

```
var url = (window.location != window.parent.location) ? document.referrer : document.location.href;
```

That will access the url of the page the document is loaded from. Wether that be directly or via an iframe.