# Get URL of embedded Google Sheet (Cross Domain)

Tags: google-apps-script, iframe, google-sheets

In my site, I am embedding a google sheet. It is critical that when somebody navigates around my sheet, I can see the URL from the parent website.

I am aware that it is normally not possible to get a cross domain URL in an iframe, but is there anything I could do in the sheet to allow this? (Google apps script maybe?)

Creative solutions are welcome, I'm desperate!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is at the `iframe` level. Apps Script won't run when viewing the spreadsheet in `iframe`.

Here you can find some workarounds that could mitigate your issue: [Access parent URL from iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420004/access-parent-url-from-iframe)