# Get full path of the parent site on which my site is loaded in an iFrame

Tags: javascript

I'm displaying my site (`www.example.com`) inside of an iFrame of another site, let's say `www.example.org`. I have to load different content on my page when iFrame is loading on a certain subpage of this site, so it should load on:

`www.example.org/subpageA`

`www.example.org/subpageB`

But shouldn't load when the site URL on which it's loaded is equal to `www.example.org/subpageC`

I tried using `document.location.ancestorOrigins[0]` for this, but it's returning only `"www.example.org"` (without the path), no matter which subpage I am, so I can't define when this certain subpage is loaded. How can I collect the full path of the source page from which my site is loaded in an iFrame, including the /subpageC part?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access parent URL from iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420004/access-parent-url-from-iframe)

Comment: Sadly, no. All of the solutions suggested there are returning the `www.example.com`, instead of what I need - `www.example.org/subpageC`.