# Get current iframe from page with JS

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a HTML page that can be opened in a different `iframe` depending on some conditions. In page execution I need to know in what `iframe` the page is running. How can I do this?

```js
/* Page A: */
if (openinA)
  $("#frameA").attr("src", "pageb.php");
else
  $("#frameB").attr("src", "pageb.php");

/* Page B: */
// Which IFRAME i am?
```

Comment: you can probably find info here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420004/access-parent-url-from-iframe (Access parent URL from iframe) .. but there are tons of restrictions

Comment: 1. jQuery is not the right tool for this, as it's a framework primarily for manipulating the DOM, not getting references to parent pages. Use plain JS. 2. See the duplicate for the answer.