# Get the current url in the iframe

Tags: php, iframe

is it possible to create page with button and iframe window, that when the user click on the button it take him to the current url of the iframe window?

Comment: `top.location.href = window.location.href;`

Comment: daverandom, but if the iframe it's google.com and the user enter to other site in the user?

Comment: Clear your question. Some code example... and what's the relation between your question and PHP?

Answer (score 2):

`document.location = document.getElementById("iframe_id").contentWindow.location` assuming your serving the Javascript from the same domain, else you'll run into [XSS vulnerabilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938180/get-current-url-from-iframe).

Comment: I need to get the serach word on goole.

Comment: @hd1's point is very salient - you won't be able to get the URL of the iframe when it is focussed on Google due to cross-domain scripting vulnerabilities. The browser simply won't let you get it.

Comment: hmm ok, so I'm can't to do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function FrameUrl()
            {
                alert('url = ' + document.frames['frame1'].location.href);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#" onclick="FrameUrl();">Find the iFrame URL</a>
        <iframe name="frame1" src="http://www.facebook.com" width="100%" height="400"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This correct as mention by "DaveRandom"

top.location.href = window.location.href