# Get URL of iFrame

Tags: jquery, url, iframe

Just wondering if anybody had any ideas on getting an iFrame's URL using possibly jQuery.

For example, if I have an iFrame on my page and somebody is scrolling through the website inside that iFrame is there a lightweight way of grabbing the current URL they are on.

Comment: you probably cannot if the iframe `src` is on a different domain due to [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/938180/get-current-url-from-iframe ?

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to do something like

```
$("#parent").get(0).contentWindow.location
```

Answer (score 1):

If someone has to ask it again. I got to make it get src using jquery and rewrite it again as I want to redraw/alter contents that has embeds. It is just, you need to pre-contain the iframe to let you have a direct selector.

```
var iframeSrc = $('.article-content iframe:first-child').attr('src');
console.log(iframeSrc);
```

Let me know if this might help.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
 var iframe = '<iframe src="http://someaddress.com" width="600" height="500"></iframe>';

 regEx = /(src)=["']([^"']*)["']/gi;

iframe.replace(regEx, function(all, type, value) {
alert(value); 
});
```

have a look http://jsfiddle.net/D8gLN/

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work if the iframe is actually in use and the user navigates inside it (which was the question).