# how to get url inside iframe2

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, asp-classic

I have `iframe` inside my website. 
inside this `iframe` user can slide into another website, which means that the `url` inside the `iframe` is changing according the page that display.
is it possible to have to `url` inside the `iframe`?

Thanks.

Comment: "is it possible to have to url inside the iframe ?" What do you mean by this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/938180/get-current-url-from-iframe

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't interact with iframe as the only interaction is the initial src (or URL) supplied to the iframe .

> "Because of the cross domain security restrictions in most Javascript
>   implementations, it’s normally impossible for one HTML document to
>   communicate with another frame, popup, or iframe unless the two pages
>   are served from the same domain. James Burke came up with a clever
>   solution to this problem, allowing bidirectional communication between
>   a parent window and it’s iframe or popup." [Source](http://makezine.com/2007/11/03/crossdomain-crossframe-javascr/)

What you are trying to do? what's your end result ... so that I can help

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for the iFrame load event and use location to get the value.

```
var frame = document.getElementById("my_iframe");
frame.addEventListener('load', function (evt) {
  console.log(frame.contentWindow.location.href);
}, false;
```

This will get you the 'URL' every time it changes.