# iFrame src change event

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iframe, onload

I've used an `Iframe` to show login page from another site. when the user entered the user and password, i want instead of opening the result login window in "iframe", it be opened in a different window. my solution is when the user is loginned, i take the current URL of :iframe", if it is the opposite of its SRC, my windows location be equale to current URl of "iframe"

```
 <iframe id="neturl" src="http://www.anotherSite.com/Login.aspx" onLoad="ChangeUrl();"  ></iframe>
```

I use javascript for find `Current url` of IFrame, But when i use this script i get error **Permission denied to access property 'href'**.

```
 function ChangeUrl()
   {
    var frame=   document.getElementById('neturl');
    alert(frame.src);
   }
```

but How to get Current url or understand that url changed?

Comment: Question isn't clear man!

Comment: are you trying to get the current url of iframe?

Comment: I use `frame.contentWindow.location.href` but don't return value.

Comment: Nillo jan, did you try: `alert(("#neturl").attr("src"));`

Comment: @Afghanistan : Thanks, i can get src of IFrame, but it is no't current ur.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/938180/get-current-url-from-iframe

Comment: I use this but don't return value.

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.location.href` to get current url.

Comment: I want to get current location of iframe.