# How to get src value from Iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I tried with a method that was suppose to work.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    alert(document.getElementById("gornji").src);

</script>

</head>

<body>
    <iframe id="gornji" src="http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp" style="width:100%; height:30%; position:absolute; top:0px; border-style:none"></iframe>


</body> 
</html>
```

What is wrong here? I am open to all answers.

Comment: nope, it doesn't. Google chrome is suppose to support this, right?

Comment: damn it, its often, isnt it ;-)

Comment: Here's Your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/938180/get-current-url-from-iframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most probably because the `iframe` is not yet part of the DOM when you try to get its property of `src`. Either place your script at the very bottom just right before end of `body` or have it attached to `window.onload` event.

Check here for a demo http://fiddle.jshell.net/doiks14/72NYm/

Comment: or move the script tag after iframe

Answer (score 1):

There is no `iframe` when your code gets executed. Execute your code after DOM is completely loaded.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    alert(document.getElementById("gornji").src);
});
```