# javascript jquery, web development

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using iframe to load lumextech.com as default `src` in a frame when i search and move to other webpage using lumextech.com But still in the `iframe` `src` its display lumextech.com only i wanted to capture url of page that has loaded in `iframe`...Notes: I don't have Control on lumextech.com....

My Code:

```
<! DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
                <section>
                    <h3> welcome to Iframe</h3>                      

                    <script type="text/javascript">


                        $(function(){
                            $('#submit').click(function(){
                               $url = $('#iframeContent').attr('src');
                               $('#demo').html($url);                               
                            });
                        });


                    </script>

                    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="showUrl"/> 
                    <div id="demo"></div> 

                    <iframe id="iframeContent" src="http://lumextech.com" style="min-height: 500px; min-width: 500px;"></iframe>               


                </section>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Same origin policy restrictions prevents such access to a iframe

Comment: There should be a way........!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a typo in your src insert function. Extra white space in the string. Work good on this [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vNaYQN)

```
$('#frameid').attr('src', 'http://lumextech.com/');
```

Comment: Ok, i remove the space but what about the main problem...... how can i get the current url........

Comment: There should... gimme  sec

Comment: Sooooo....... this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/938180/get-current-url-from-iframe

Comment: Yeah my bad looks like no go. Good luck

Comment: contentWindow.location.herf works only if the iframe is in the same domain but i'm working wit different domain... I think it's not possible ........ Browser will not give that permission.............