# How to check URL of "iframe" inside main page

Tags: javascript, php, html, web-services, iframe

I have index.html page as main page for my webside. All remaining pages are inside `iframe` of index.html page. How do i get to know in which page i am working when i open on browser. Because url is giving only index.html

Comment: I think something similar was described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/938195/7698162

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get current URL from IFRAME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938180/get-current-url-from-iframe)

Comment: Thanks i got this answer..