# Get iframe (from different domain) URL params

Tags: javascript, url, iframe

I have and iframe (from different domain) on my site and would like to get it's URL params. For security reasons I was unable to get it (I don't own the iframe domain).

Does someone know a way around this? I just need the URL params to send the information to Google Anlytics.

Best,
Anna

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938180/get-current-url-from-iframe

Comment: Do you own both domains or only one of them?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, unless you control both domains; in which case you could just have the iframe contents tell Google Analytics (or your own API) what the GET params are.

Otherwise, you are asking for a way to circumvent browser security features, and there isn't one (or rather, there isn't one that anyone would be willing to share, or has been found yet).

Comment: I was afraid of that. I own just one of the domais. But thx :)