# Get the URL of the webpage displayed in an <object>

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, object, dom

I have div which contains an HTML `object`

```
<div id="webPage">
  <object type="text/html" id="webUrl" data="http://www.pageweb.com" style="overflow:auto"></object>
</div>
```

In this div the user has the ability to navigate to the `http://www.pageweb.com` site. I would like to retrieve the exact URL where the user is, for example: `http://www.pageweb.com/fr/index.php?page=cadre&option=5`. I am unable to find the properties of this object, or its child, in order to retrieve this URL.

When I right click the `object` in Chrome and click "Display the source code of the frame", it displays the content the URL that I need.

Comment: Why are you using `<object>`?

Comment: Something like this should help : https://stackoverflow.com/q/938180/9387017

Comment: This what-s my first idea. What do you propose ?

Comment: Not possible with IFrame because it is Cross-Domain ! :(

Answer (score 0):

Might be missing something - but surly you just want the `data` property of the object.

```js
var element = document.getElementById('webUrl');

console.log(element.data);
```

```html
<div id="webPage">
    <object type="text/html" id="webUrl" data="http://www.pageweb.com" style="overflow:auto">
    </object>
</div>
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to know the page the user is on as the navigate, not just the page that's initially loaded. Could be wrong, the question is lacking a lot of useful detail/

Comment: Correct Rory.Thanks