# How to get the current url of an iframe

Tags: javascript, url, iframe

I need to find the url of an iframe that will update if a user clicks on a link in the iframe.

i tried using answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938180/get-current-url-from-iframe) ([[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63670468/21243967) [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/938195/21243967))
but it errored

> VM98:7 Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
> at iframe.onload (:7:46)

Comment: Could it be that the link leaves your domain? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938180/get-current-url-from-iframe/938195#938195

Comment: As the answer you linked to states: `For security reasons, you can only get the url for as long as the contents of the iframe, and the referencing javascript, are served from the same domain`. As this is not the case for you - as demonstrated by the error you're getting - then what you're attempting to do is not possible from client-side JS.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('your-iframe-id'); // Replace 'your-iframe id' with the actual ID of your iframe 
var currentURL = iframe.src;

console.log(currentURL); // Print the current URL of the iframe
```

Comment: It didn't update when i clicked on a link in the iframe, it just printed the original url