# Different output during event listener in Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, iframe

Problem is that I need to get URL from IFrame(baseURI) when I console log iFrameRef. It shows correct version of IFrame. But when I console log `iFrameRef.current!.baseURI`, it shows the old version of iFrame.

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const iframe = iFrameRef.current;
        if (iframe) {
            iframe.addEventListener('load', () => {
                console.log('IFRAME', iFrameRef);
                console.log('CURRENT', iFrameRef.current!.baseURI);
            });

            return () => {
                iframe.removeEventListener('load', () => {});
            };
        }
    }, [dependency]);
```

'dependency' is when something happens to url inside of iframe.

I expect to get the last version of IFrame.

Comment: Is `baseURI` supposed to be anything react-specific? Or is this basically just accessing https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/baseURI ? If the latter, then it is clear why this doesn't work as you expected.

Comment: no, not react-specific, just accessing what you send!

Comment: _"returns the absolute base URL of the document **containing the node**"_ - so this gets you the base URL of the document that _contains_ your iframe element, not of the iframe element itself. You would need to check what the actual `location` of the iframe's content window is (https://stackoverflow.com/a/938195/1427878) - but that will only work, if the iframe was loaded from the same origin, as the parent document. For iframes that load external content, this simply _must not_ work, for security reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to a security restriction in the browser, the only solution is to add JavaScript to each page to send the parent page a message when it loads with the new URI