# Is it possible to tell if the src of an iFrame has changed?

Tags: javascript, iframe

Is it possible to tell if the source of an iFrame has redirected the client to another page? And if so, tell what page the client got redirected to?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759896/find-out-if-iframe-url-has-been-changed

Answer (score 5):

`onload` event

like

```
<iframe src="http://www.mydomain/" onLoad="alert('fire');"></iframe>
```

The alert will pop-up whenever the location within the iframe has changed.
check it out [here also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759896/find-out-if-iframe-url-has-been-changed)

Here is a question explaining how to [get current location of an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44359/how-do-i-get-the-current-location-of-an-iframe)

Comment: Ah, look at that! Great stuff, however ... I think this only applies to same-origin frames.

Comment: Nothing will let you spy on what the user does on a different origin.

Comment: No, but this is not directly spying though - is it? It's not like I'm using JS to parse the response the server spits back. All I want to do is to check if the xmlhttpobject got a certain HTTP payback and then try to filter out what HTTP url it got redirect to. I know JS is restricted, but this should be possible. I had a look at Microsofts API for the IE proposal some other user posted, didn't quite get it to work though.

Answer (score 1):

The src attribute won't change if the iframe navigates to a new page, but the location of the iframe's contentWindow will.

If you start the iframe in a page on your own domain you can use the iframes onload event to read iframe.contentWindow.location.href.

Use a try-block, and if it fails because of a cross domain call, you can return that the iframe is now in **some** remote site.

If it returns a value you can return the url on your site the iframe has navigated to.

Comment: That sounds exactly like what I

Answer (score 0):

Allright, so I've been fiddeling with this script for a while now and I think I've reached a conclusion which I think is worth sharing. Cross-domain is pretty strict, and as far as I know there is no way of telling what url the xmlhttprequest object got passed on to. I did however notice a solution on another site where they suggest using a hidden iFrame (I'm referring to the link in @ayush's answer).