# Go to iframe when src changes

Tags: html, xhtml, iframe

I am working on a new [home](http://zac.gorak.us/home/) for my browser.

When the src changes of the iframe (click search or something) I want to leave my site and go to where the iframe is going. How do I do this?

edit:// example: [http://imgur.com/OvnCz.jpg](https://imgur.com/OvnCz.jpg)

Comment: So really, what you want to do is detect navigation events on a framed page, potentially one you don't control?

Comment: I suppose so. When the src of the page changes, go to that page.

Comment: If I can accomplish this without an iframe, that is fine. 

It seems like what I want is almost impossible with an iframe though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44359/how-do-i-get-the-current-location-of-an-iframe

Comment: I don't think that's going to turn out to be possible unless the framed page cooperates in some manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put a target attribute on the link with a value of _top, like this:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_top">Google</a>
```

That tells the browser to open the link in the top-most frame, that is the whole browser window. More information can be found [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/present/frames.html#h-16.3)

Comment: That works for links, but not frames. I don't think this will work. See edit.