# Access iFrame URL with JQuery / Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a page like this...

```
<div>
<iframe id="mainContent">
<iframe id="littleBox">
</div>
```

and I want to do this...

```
 $(".someButton").live('click', function() {
       alert(/*The URL That the Main Frame is ON*/);
 });
```

I found this: `$("#mainFrame").get(0).location.href`, but it doesnt work...

Also, I need it to return the current url, so if someone navigates around it should return the current page they are on.

Comment: Same question asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44359/how-do-i-get-the-current-location-of-an-iframe

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Okay so you mean you have to access the URL of the parent from the child iframe?

```
$("#mainFrame").get(0).contentWindow.location
```

Comment: The parent frame (untitled div in my example) needs to access the CURRENT url of the child iframe.  The problem is that after naviagting to a different url from the starting url of the child iframe, I am still getting the original starting URL of the child iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Does iframe.src not work? Or, are you trying to get the parent document? In that case, you can just use `parent`.

Answer (score 0):

As Azmisov says iframe.src does the trick

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>iframe Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ShowURLs() {
            var control = document.getElementById("mainContent");
            alert("iframe source = " + control.src);
            alert("this page = " + location.href);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <input type="button" id="someButton" value="Click Me" onclick="ShowURLs()" />
        <div>
            <iframe id="mainContent" src="Test.aspx" />
            <iframe id="littleBox" />
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: No it doesn't. iframe.src returns the original url.  In your case even if you navigate away from Test.aspx it will return Test.aspx as the src. Just add a link on Test.aspx to SomethingElse.aspx and then click the button again... The desired output would be SomethingElse.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('mainContent').contentWindow.location.href
```