# How do you access the current location of an iframe?

Tags: iframe, https, location

The problem is I'm using an iframe to process a login form via POST over https, but the parent hosting the iframe is http (although in the same domain)

is this doable?

I can't test this quite yet because I can only use https in our staging environment.

Thanks

```
  function process_form(f){


    var l = $("iframe#loginFrame");    
    if(l.length==0){      
      f.attr("target","loginFrame");      
      $('<iframe src="/player.htm?ajax=1"'+(!_DBG?' class="hide"':'')+' id="loginFrame" name="loginFrame"></iframe>').prependTo('body');      
      $("iframe#loginFrame").load(function() {
        var u = this.contentWindow.location;


        if(String(u).indexOf("confirm")>=0){ 
          change_form(1);
        }else if(u!=this.src){
          change_form(0);
        }
        log(u);
        log(this.src);

      });



    }else{
      warn("Frame already exists!"); 
    }

    change_form(-1);
    setTimeout(function(){ f.submit();},500);
    log(f);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `document.getElementById('iframename').src` what you're looking for?

**EDIT**

It appears that this has been [previously answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44359/how-do-i-get-the-current-location-of-an-iframe). Try `document.getElementById("iframename").documentWindow.location.href`.

Comment: i tried that. I get an documentWindow not defined error =/ (prefer with jquery)

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, yes.  To access the location of an iframe, btw, use `myIframe.contentWindow.location`.  See http://www-archive.mozilla.org/docs/dom/domref/dom_frame_ref16.html for details.

Two frames in different protocols (http vs https) are in different origins, so you can't do anything that requires same-origin privileges.

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy#Origin_determination_rules

> The term "origin" is defined using the
>   domain name, **application layer
>   protocol**, and (in most browsers) TCP
>   port of the HTML document running the
>   script.

But the location should be accessible regardless of same-origin policy.

Comment: yes.  It works regardless of the protocol of the accessing origin or the iframe.

Comment: in my test of this, I was not able to retrieve the URL of the iframe when it was https from the parent http

Answer (score 1):

you might be able to in your child frame call the parent so when the child frame loads you could do

domReady{
  parent.form.hiddenField.value = document.location.href
}

basically you pass from child back to parent.  You'll have to experiment if the child can call a method in the parent which you might be able to do and pass the location to that method