# How to check if user is in a specific site within an <object> navigator in your site

Tags: html, web, object, embed

I have a webpage with this code:

```
<object data=http://<?php echo $_GET['wp'];?> width="600" height="400"> <embed src=http://<?php echo $_GET['wp'];?> width="600" height="400"> </embed> Error: Embedded data could not be displayed. </object>
```

I'd like to know if the user through navigation manages to get to a specific site within the

```
<object>.
```

Is that possible?

If not, is there another way to embed a webpage within a website that allows me to know in which webpage he is in?

EDIT: What if we know some of the context of the source code the target page has and we just need to see if the page within the page contains this part of the code, is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an iframe!

```
var url =
   document.getElementById('my-iframe').src;
```

Edit: As Ant mentioned, you can't get the url from an `iframe` tag unless domain of the page in the `iframe` matches the page containing the `iframe`.

Comment: good idea, but I need a little more help...
I changed the code into:
`<iframe name="site" frameborder="0" height="1000" src="http://<?php echo $_GET['wp'];?>"target="_blank" width="620" scrolling="Auto";> </iframe>`
and tried this:
`<script type="text/javascript">
function currentpage()
{
alert(document.getElementById('site').contentWindow.location.href);
}
</script>`
...
`<form>
<input type="button" value="Click me!" onclick="currentpage()" />
</form>`
but when I click on the button nothing happens

Comment: You need to add the `id` attribute to the `<iframe>` tag. You're using the `name` attribute instead.

Comment: I just found this question, which seems to provide the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44359/how-do-i-get-the-current-location-of-an-iframe

Comment: so, it seems it is not possible except if the user navigates within the same domain the `<iframe>` is...
Anyway, thanks a lot for hinting what I should look into...