# Retrieve the complete URL from an iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, href

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get the current location of an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44359/how-do-i-get-the-current-location-of-an-iframe)

Hi i want to get the complete URL, and with the methods i know i get the full url but of the iframe, and i want the 'final' document.location.href,

how can i get it?

i don't care if its php or js, but i'm guessing by my experiments that with PHp it's not possible...

Comment: Considering PHP is serverside and you're asking a clientside question, not so much. Do you want to know what the full URL is of the iFrame?

Comment: no, lets say i am an iframe i want to know where i am :)

Comment: i checked that ussing search previous posting, and not.. that would be the oposite

Comment: amazing. so you close my question and you point me to an oposite one. well, first weird experience with stkoverflow.........

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know where you **currently are**:

- Client side - javascript - you can use `alert(window.location)`.
- Server side - php - `.$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` or `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` depending on what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [top answer from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44359/how-do-i-get-the-current-location-of-an-iframe).

It's important to note that it's (luckily!) not possible to get the URL of an `iframe` if the `iframe`'s URL is from a different domain than the parent page. If you're trying to do that, you're probably out of luck.