# How to get the url from a frame?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, frame

I have this jsp page that includes the following frames:

```
<frameset cols="20%,*">
    <frame src=”SideBar.jsp” name="frameA">
    <frame src=”http://www.w3schools.com/” name="frameB" target="_self">
</frameset>
```

In frameB,it's an external link, the user can navigate that webpage and click on links and do stuff. Is there a way when the user clicks on a link, to get the url of that new webpage? e.g. http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp

Thanks in advance

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44359/how-do-i-get-the-current-location-of-an-iframe/836393#836393 (IE only) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44359/how-do-i-get-the-current-location-of-an-iframe/666832#666832 (iframe).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
alert(frameB.location);
```

Depending on the browser, this may be disabled [due to security reasons](http://www.irt.org/script/94.htm).

(You don't know when the user clicked a page, so you should check in regular intervals if it changed.)