# Getting the URL of an iFrame cross domain and protocol in jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am basically creating an external shopping cart system for users on my site that will lead to a secure system that I am paying for, and in their shopping pages, they auto-generate a PHP GET variable called `CFTOKEN` that I need to access so I can send cart updates.

I am loading an iframe with the URL that redirects to the shopping cart with the `CFTOKEN` variable in the URL. I need to get this variable in javascript so I can send updates to the cart.

I have tried accessing the URL by the following code:

```
$("#iframe").contents().get(0).location.href
```

but I not only get a cross domain error, I get `undefined` for the location.

How can I get the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply can't in modern browsers, it would've been a security issue. I'm sorry.

You can read more about it here: [How do I get the current location of an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44359/how-do-i-get-the-current-location-of-an-iframe)

Comment: Any suggestions on a loophole for me?

Comment: So basically what you want is that the main application wants access to `CFTOKEN` which is a value used for authenticating and updating the cart. Do you have control over the cart or is it a separate system? Could you write some sort of method there for fetching it based upon the same user input as it's created?

Comment: I have no access to any of the cart functions, etc. All I need is that one variable. That variable is also embedded in the source code of the page, if there's any way I could get it that way.