# Get the url of an external iframe

Tags: php, javascript, cross-browser

I want to retrive the url of an external `iframe`.

The url I can see in my browser, but how can I get the url of that what can I see in the browser via JS or PHP?

- **Preview Image 1 :**
  [image]
- **Preview Image 2 :**
  [image]

After I click the blue hovered firefox menu item in Preview Image 1, I get the results that I want in firefox.

How to obtain this in JS?

Comment: What do you mean by _external_ iframe?

Answer (score 0):

In javascript: Look for the src of the iframe, which is in the HTML code. You could get the iframe by id or by tag, and then get the src property of it.

Comment: src is not useful. i need the endpage where te user has navigated

Answer (score 0):

you can do this via javascript.

```
var url = document.getElementById("myiframe").src;
```

where `myiframe` is the ID attribute of your iframe.

trying to do this in php would require you to parse the dom.

this this working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/96Mcg/)

#### UPDATE

You can use jquery for this

```
var url = $('#myiframe').contents().get(0).location.href;
```

alse you will have to identify browser specific `documentWindow` object to get the `.location.href` value.

This issue is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44359/how-do-i-get-the-current-location-of-an-iframe).

Comment: i have cheked this its working, right. In my case the problem is that the url will redirect the user so it only grabs the url that i have entered at my html code. The main idea behind this was to get the end url where the website has redirected me

Comment: This solution only works if your target browsers are not using "anti.-cross-origin" policy.