# Getting notified about iframe loading

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am developing an extension where I need to get notified whenever an iframe is loaded and ready. I used `page-mod` but I don't get the expected output. This is my code:

```
var data = require("sdk/self").data;
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");

pageMod.PageMod({
 include: ['*'],
 contentScriptFile: data.url("pageNavData.js"),
 contentScriptWhen: "ready",
 attachTo: ["frame"],
 onAttach: function(worker) {
  worker.port.on("gotElement", function(elementContent) {
    console.log(elementContent);
  });
 }
});
```

And `pageNavData.js` is:

```
self.port.emit("gotElement", document.location.href);
```

Can anybody see what is wrong with this?

Comment: The code looks fine. What output are you seeing? [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1245166/1720014) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that the `"gotElement"` message is emitted before the listener is attached.

You can fix it with:

```
setTimeout(_ => self.port.emit("gotElement", document.location.href));
```

Afaict you don't need the contentScript, just do what you wanted to do in the `onAttach` handler.