# Reload a page inside iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have an `iframe` and I want to reload the currently displayed page on button press.

HTML:

```
<iframe id="webView"></iframe>
```

JS:

```
function reloadPage()
{
    var webView = document.getElementById("webView");

    //CODE
}
```

Inside the `reloadPage()` method I tried different solutions:

### Call reload()

```
webView.contentWindow.location.reload();
```

This just doesn't work because the pages loaded inside the iframe are from a different domain than the main page.

### Set src

```
webView.src = wevView.src;
```

It gives wrong result because it contains the initial url that I set to the iframe, non the current one.

### Set location

```
webView.contentWindow.location = webView.contentWindow.location
```

I was expecting it to not work with urls from different domains (the same as calling reload()), but actually it works and also gives a good result.
Good but not perfect: the `location` object holds the current url but strips any parameter.

For example if the frame is currently displaying the following url:

```
http://www.myserver.com/thatsite/?page_id=11
```

the `location` object contains this url:

```
http://www.myserver.com/thatsite/
```

So this one works well as long as there are no parameters in the url.

### Better solution?

I rely heavly on urls with parameters (mostly WordPress installations) so i need a way to keep them while reloading.
Anyone knows a solution to achieve this?

Comment: have you tried to set the iframe's src to nothing, wait a short time, and reset it again?

Comment: That is not the problem, the src=src method works without the need to wait.  I need a way to get the current url, complete with all the parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just not possible, see this thread:

[Get current URL from IFRAME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938180/get-current-url-from-iframe)

and this one

[How do I get the current location of an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44359/how-do-i-get-the-current-location-of-an-iframe)

Comment: Is it normal that i can access and even set contentWindow.location?
I was expecting not to be able to access anything under contentWindow, and this is stated two times in your first link.

* If you try to access documentWindow.location.href **(or anything under documentWindow)** and the iframe is in a page that doesn't belong to the domain of the containing window, it will raise an exception
* By the way **you can't access cross-domain iframe location** at all.

I'm a bit confused about it.
I'm experienced in C++, C# and Java but i'm new to js and html so i don't know where some boundaries are

Comment: not that firm with iframes, especially cross origin, as i try not to use them (and you should do the same), sorry...

Answer (score 0):

Since setting location works, you could use location.search to retrieve the GET parameters and reconstruct the URL that way.

Example:

```
webView.contentWindow.location = webView.contentWindow.location + webView.contentWindow.location.search
```

Comment: will not work because of cross origin policy (his iframe url is from a different domain)

Comment: `webView.contentWindow.location.search` gives `Error: Permission denied to access property 'search'`, the same error i get when i try to call `reload()`. And i really don't understand why i can read and even set `location`, but i can't read anything inside it.