# How to copy original URL from a iframe?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

I have to display multiple site pages on my website.

I would like to display one page from each site on a single page.

I guess it is best to use `iframe`?

How could a user copy the URL of the original webpage out of the `iframe`?

Currently I use YouTube embedded iFrame

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" 
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8gESFEtIx1A" frameborder="0" 
    allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

Comment: So you are trying to give users option to copy the webpage address, that is loaded inside an `iframe` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44359/how-do-i-get-the-current-location-of-an-iframe