# Load on a IFrame, using angular 2+

Tags: javascript, html, angular, iframe

I need to put a loader every time my iframe navigate for another url. 
I think it may be possible, with a logic like:

```
onLoad(Iframe: ElementRef) {
  this.Hide();
}

onNavigate(Iframe: ElementRef) { // this event does not exist
  this.show();
}
```

Do anyone has a idea of how to make it?

Comment: you mean this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520043/how-to-detect-a-route-change-in-angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's a similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44359/how-do-i-get-the-current-location-of-an-iframe)

There're no navigation events on iframes, you can only get initial load on src property change. So if there is a SPA running in iframe, you will need to retreive it manually:

I would suggest you to use ngAfterViewCheck and retreive location like this

`this.iframeLocation = iframeRef.nativeElement.contentWindow.location.href;`

Main problem: browser will not allow you to get location if iframe is cross-origin.